# Systemd: Messages are logged at the end of script execution

Tags: django, logging, service, systemd

I have Django site that have custom management command that sync data from one system to database every 5 min. In the script for the command there is serveral log messages. When I manually execute the command, everything is working fine and each log message is outputed to stdout/stderr at the time as it should be. No problem here.

For running the command every 5min, I setup systemd service and timer and it is working as it should be with one minor thing. All messsages from the script are logged in systemd at the time when the script execution ended, not at the time when they happened. The script is usually running about one minute and log message is outputed sporadically as each subtask in the script has ended. In my case, systemd logged all messages as if they happend at the same time, more precisely at the end of execution.

So, log is looking something like this and pay attention on timestamp of messages.

```
Jul 16 09:20:01 SmallServer systemd[1]: Started DjngoSite Sync daemon.
Jul 16 09:20:40 SmallServer python[21265]: Task 1 completed
Jul 16 09:20:40 SmallServer python[21265]: Task 2 completed
Jul 16 09:20:40 SmallServer python[21265]: Task 3 completed
Jul 16 09:20:40 SmallServer python[21265]: Task 4 completed
Jul 16 09:20:40 SmallServer python[21265]: Sync ended
```

But, I want to look like this:

```
Jul 16 09:20:01 SmallServer systemd[1]: Started DjngoSite Sync daemon.
Jul 16 09:20:11 SmallServer python[21265]: Task 1 completed
Jul 16 09:20:15 SmallServer python[21265]: Task 2 completed
Jul 16 09:20:22 SmallServer python[21265]: Task 3 completed
Jul 16 09:20:39 SmallServer python[21265]: Task 4 completed
Jul 16 09:20:40 SmallServer python[21265]: Sync ended
```

I cannot figure out is this issue with systemd or with Django. I am writing messages to the stdout as it is shown in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Answer (score 0):

Python is buffering what is written to stdout.
What helps is to set enviromental variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`

- [Enviromental variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED)
- [Python `-u` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)

With Python version 3.7 was changed that the text layer of the stdout and stderr streams now is unbuffered.